# What could be reasons to let all developers login to Jenkins?

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, audit

We're in process of adding Jenkins CI to a project with 100 developers.

Do you think they all need read-only access to Jenkins? or should it be accessed by 5 developers only who take charge of builds and continuous testing?
What could be reasons to let all developers login to Jenkins?

It's about security, auditing, Jenkins pipelines etc.
and technically (if relevant) it can be integrated with LDAP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about workplace administration

Comment: It's about Jenkins security ...

Comment: I'd say: do not close the question. I was able to give a pretty technical answer below, so it looks technical enough ot me :-) To me, the question is about usage of a tool, not internal administration.

Comment: I see now the question is not so clear ... I meant if ALL developers need read-only access to Jenkins (to see dashboard and logs in case of failures).
Of course not all developers need admin ( or read+write) access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if 100 developers will be admin of Jenkins , I think that after several weeks someone will mess it up.

you should have several admins for it , to verify plugin before installation.

I used the [role plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) , and define several roles for Jenkins :
admins
builders
configures
readers
team leaders ( with more permissions than configures)

Answer (score 1):

There might be an easy technical solution to your problem: [Jenkinsfile + pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/)

Then only one or two people need admin access for adding nodes and perhaps a password or two and some initial setup. **Configuring the builds** is done solely through a `Jenkinsfile` per repository.

That way, every developer with push access to the repo can configure the jenkins job for that repo. All in version control, so everyone will behave themselves.

LDAP/active directory integration is possible. In my setup, as an example, I've made login mandatory. Everyone that's logged in (=the developers) can stop/restart jobs. Only myself can do the rest of the maintentance. Very simple and clear and long-term-clean setup.